# python unable to identify else statements

Tags: python, if-statement, pylance

```
from requests import *
import json
import base64
import urllib
from cmd import Cmd

url = "http://api.response.htb/"
url_digest = "cab532f75001ed2cc94ada92183d2160319a328e67001a9215956a5dbf10c545"


def get(url, url_digest): data = {
    "url": url,
    "url_digest": url_digest,
    "method": "GET",
    "session": "5f7bf45b02c832cf5b40c15ab6d365af",
    "session_digest": "a2b9ac69ab85795d13d12857a709a024cd729dcdf2c3fd3bb21ed514bc9990ac"
}


headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
url_proxy = "http://proxy.response.htb/fetch"
s = Session()
res = s.post(url_proxy, json=data, headers=headers)
body = json.loads(res.text)['body']
body = base64.b64decode(body)
if "zip" in url:
    f = open("file.zip", "wb")
f.write(body)
f.close()
print("Done saving file :-");

else: print body


def url_de(url):
    s = Session()


res = s.get('http://www.response.htb/status/main.js.php',
            cookies={'PHPSESSID': url})
x = res.text.find("session_digest':'")
y = res.text.find("'};")
return res.text[x+17:y]


class pr(Cmd):
    prompt = "==> "


def default(self, url): url_digest = url_de(url)


get(url, url_digest)
def do_exit(self, a): exit()


pr().cmdloop()
```

at line 32 vs code is giving an error message as expected expression pylance and unable to proceed further. please anyone help me to solve this error. i am getting two error one is in else and another is at return statement at line 43. so if anyone can able to identify the error and help me out to solve this please help me.

[image: Error Line]

Comment: you have code that is not indented inside the if statement. You also have some lines ending with `;`

Comment: I'd suggest you go line by line. You have multiple errors in your code, not just indentation ones. You have print statements without parenthesis, so they will fail if you run the code in python 3. You need to check each line of code, indent it appropriately and check for syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation is significant in Python.

You have one line after your `if` indented, then lines which are not indented. This means the conditional is finished. You then have an `else` by itself, which is not permitted.

You likely meant:

```
if "zip" in url:
    f = open("file.zip", "wb")
    f.write(body)
    f.close()
    print("Done saving file :-");
else: 
    print(body)
```

But this would be improved by using a context manager:

```
if "zip" in url:
    with open("file.zip", "wb") as f:
        f.write(body)
    print("Done saving file :-");
else: 
    print(body)
```

Comment: so what i can do , i need all lines to be intended in if statement please just modify for me .!

Comment: this solved the if else statement but what about the return statement. it says it may be under a function

Comment: The same applies to functions. As soon as you lose the indentation, you're no longer "in"
 the function.

Comment: please help me out i am a beginner to python not have an much idea about it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is your code scope

Just indent 28-30 and 38-43 line , then part 1,2 will into if scope
part 3,4 into func scope

Comment: please help me to do so i am unable to do it to the return function.

Comment: @PiyushShrivastava just indent  38-43 line as the answer said. In python ,  indent decide the scope of code